# Adding taking screenshot in Allure [Java - Selenium]

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, screenshot, allure

I have a problem integrating my automated tests written in selenium - java with support for taking screenshot in allure. I have created an interface that works well. Basic picture taking (saving to folder.
Below I inserted code:

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //screenshot

        try {
            b.getScreenshot(result.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I converted it by adding it to:

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //screenshot

        try {
            b.getScreenshot(result.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Allure.addAttachment("screenShot", new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot)result.getTestContext().getAttribute("WebDriver")).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));

        Object webDriverAttribute = result.getTestContext().getAttribute("WebDriver");
        captureScreenshot((WebDriver) webDriverAttribute);
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't want to act. I am asking for help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I added something this for my interface

```
@Attachment
    public byte[] captureScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
```